# How to convert HTML entities to plain text in YQL or Y! Pipes?

Tags: yql, yahoo-pipes

I have the source in html entities (eg: `&#99;&#111;&#118;&#101;&#114;`)
I want to convert them into simple readable plain text (eg: `abcdef`...)

how can i do that using YQL or Yahoo Pipes?
(eg: i want to convert `&#99;&#111;&#118;&#101;&#114;` into `cover` using YQL or Yahoo pipes)

Comment: How do you currently get the HTML entities? Would you be up for creating a [data table](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-creating-opentables-chapter.html) (within which you can run  JavaScript to do the decoding)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following components:

- A [yql stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461474/performing-image-scrapping-using-yql-with-lowest-resources-usage-possible-i-e-l/18623731#18623731)

> select * from xslt where url="//foo.html" and stylesheet="//bar.xsl"

- An [entity declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203690/dtd-entities-vs-xml-schema-elements)

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet[
  <!ENTITY 99 "c">
  <!ENTITY 111 "o">
  <!ENTITY 118 "v">
  <!ENTITY 101 "e">
  <!ENTITY 114 "r">
  ]>
  ```

**References**

- [XML Entity Definitions for Characters (2nd Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-entity-names/)